# New contacts class and error - app was stopped - Android

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I created a new class in Android Project, which is reading a contacts from phonebook. This class is:

```
public class KontaktBook extends Activity {
    public void displayContacts() {
        Toast.makeText(KontaktBook.this, "Name:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        Toast.makeText(KontaktBook.this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In main class, I was create new KontaktBook object, like this:

```
    KontaktBook kont = new KontaktBook();
    kont.displayContacts();
```

And when I put this program into Android phone and induce kont.displayContacts();

I receive error in phone: "Unfortunately,aplication was stopped".

Where can be a problem?

When I put this fragment (in metod displayContacts()) into Main Class (MainActivity), the problem disappears - no problem.

PS
Logcat shows:

```
08-10 13:32:15.080  11584-11584/com.example.proj E/dalvikvm﹕ could not disable core file generation for pid 11584: Operation not permitted
08-10 13:32:15.200  11584-11584/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
08-10 13:32:15.200  11584-11584/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12214: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
08-10 13:32:15.200  11584-11584/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
08-10 13:32:15.200  11584-11584/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12220: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
08-10 13:32:15.200  11584-11584/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
08-10 13:32:15.200  11584-11584/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9785: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
08-10 13:32:15.210  11584-11584/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
08-10 13:32:15.210  11584-11584/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 392: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
08-10 13:32:15.210  11584-11584/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
08-10 13:32:15.210  11584-11584/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 414: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
08-10 13:32:15.210  11584-11584/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
08-10 13:32:15.210  11584-11584/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 355: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-10 13:32:15.220  11584-11584/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
08-10 13:32:15.220  11584-11584/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 357: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-10 13:32:15.350  11584-11584/com.example.proj W/linker﹕ library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
08-10 13:32:15.350  11584-11584/com.example.proj W/linker﹕ error:
08-10 13:32:42.140  12032-12032/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
08-10 13:32:42.140  12032-12032/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12214: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
08-10 13:32:42.140  12032-12032/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
08-10 13:32:42.140  12032-12032/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12220: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
08-10 13:32:42.150  12032-12032/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
08-10 13:32:42.150  12032-12032/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9785: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
08-10 13:32:42.160  12032-12032/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
08-10 13:32:42.160  12032-12032/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 392: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
08-10 13:32:42.160  12032-12032/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
08-10 13:32:42.160  12032-12032/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 414: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
08-10 13:32:42.160  12032-12032/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
08-10 13:32:42.170  12032-12032/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 355: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-10 13:32:42.170  12032-12032/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
08-10 13:32:42.170  12032-12032/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 357: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-10 13:32:42.330  12032-12032/com.example.proj W/linker﹕ library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
08-10 13:32:42.330  12032-12032/com.example.proj W/linker﹕ error:
08-10 13:32:42.990  12032-12032/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41774c50)
08-10 13:39:02.080  12396-12396/com.example.proj E/dalvikvm﹕ could not disable core file generation for pid 12396: Operation not permitted
08-10 13:39:02.210  12396-12396/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
08-10 13:39:02.210  12396-12396/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12214: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
08-10 13:39:02.210  12396-12396/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
08-10 13:39:02.210  12396-12396/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12220: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
08-10 13:39:02.220  12396-12396/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
08-10 13:39:02.220  12396-12396/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9785: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
08-10 13:39:02.230  12396-12396/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
08-10 13:39:02.230  12396-12396/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 392: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
08-10 13:39:02.230  12396-12396/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
08-10 13:39:02.230  12396-12396/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 414: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
08-10 13:39:02.250  12396-12396/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
08-10 13:39:02.250  12396-12396/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 355: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-10 13:39:02.250  12396-12396/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
08-10 13:39:02.250  12396-12396/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 357: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-10 13:39:02.450  12396-12396/com.example.proj W/linker﹕ library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
08-10 13:39:02.450  12396-12396/com.example.proj W/linker﹕ error:
08-10 13:39:22.320  12620-12620/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
08-10 13:39:22.320  12620-12620/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12214: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
08-10 13:39:22.320  12620-12620/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
08-10 13:39:22.330  12620-12620/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12220: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
08-10 13:39:22.330  12620-12620/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
08-10 13:39:22.330  12620-12620/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9785: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
08-10 13:39:22.340  12620-12620/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
08-10 13:39:22.340  12620-12620/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 392: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
08-10 13:39:22.340  12620-12620/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
08-10 13:39:22.340  12620-12620/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 414: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
08-10 13:39:22.350  12620-12620/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
08-10 13:39:22.350  12620-12620/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 355: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-10 13:39:22.350  12620-12620/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
08-10 13:39:22.350  12620-12620/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 357: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-10 13:39:22.500  12620-12620/com.example.proj W/linker﹕ library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
08-10 13:39:22.500  12620-12620/com.example.proj W/linker﹕ error:
08-10 13:39:23.830  12620-12620/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41774c50)
08-10 13:39:25.670  12620-12620/com.example.proj I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 12620 SIG: 9
08-10 13:40:00.660  12848-12848/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
08-10 13:40:00.660  12848-12848/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12214: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
08-10 13:40:00.660  12848-12848/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
08-10 13:40:00.660  12848-12848/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12220: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
08-10 13:40:00.670  12848-12848/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
08-10 13:40:00.670  12848-12848/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9785: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
08-10 13:40:00.680  12848-12848/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
08-10 13:40:00.680  12848-12848/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 392: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
08-10 13:40:00.680  12848-12848/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
08-10 13:40:00.680  12848-12848/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 414: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
08-10 13:40:00.690  12848-12848/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
08-10 13:40:00.690  12848-12848/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 355: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-10 13:40:00.690  12848-12848/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
08-10 13:40:00.690  12848-12848/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 357: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-10 13:40:00.800  12848-12848/com.example.proj W/linker﹕ library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
08-10 13:40:00.800  12848-12848/com.example.proj W/linker﹕ error:
08-10 13:40:02.170  12848-12848/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41774c50)
08-10 13:52:03.510  13264-13264/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
08-10 13:52:03.510  13264-13264/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12214: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
08-10 13:52:03.510  13264-13264/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
08-10 13:52:03.510  13264-13264/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12220: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
08-10 13:52:03.510  13264-13264/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
08-10 13:52:03.510  13264-13264/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9785: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
08-10 13:52:03.530  13264-13264/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
08-10 13:52:03.530  13264-13264/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 392: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
08-10 13:52:03.530  13264-13264/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
08-10 13:52:03.530  13264-13264/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 414: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
08-10 13:52:03.540  13264-13264/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
08-10 13:52:03.540  13264-13264/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 355: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-10 13:52:03.540  13264-13264/com.example.proj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
08-10 13:52:03.540  13264-13264/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 357: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-10 13:52:03.750  13264-13264/com.example.proj W/linker﹕ library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
08-10 13:52:03.750  13264-13264/com.example.proj W/linker﹕ error:
08-10 13:52:16.480  13264-13264/com.example.proj W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41774c50)
08-10 13:57:16.560  13264-13264/com.example.proj I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 13264 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Intent to start KontaktBook activity and you can call display Contacts method inside on Create method of KontaktBook Activity as you have declared it as Activity. Remove extend Activity from KontaktBook class to directly call display Contacts method from your Main Activity.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I will try use the intent. By the way - I would like to ask, why in Android i can't create KontaktBook object? In Java on PC everything is OK and I don't gain any errors...